# Can not execute sudo commands on aws ec2 instance ssh http all ports are off

Tags: sudo, aws, uid

recently I have been facing a serious issue on one of my servers. While accessing my server with **solar putty** on windows I got **error accessing the server** message on the response. So I tried from my server console but I couldn't access the server. Later I got access with the AWS systems manager with an ssm-agent new user account. But, I can not start or run any service from that user account. It says to use the **sudo** command but whenever I try sudo the server gives me the following error.

```
sh-4.2$ sudo yum install polkit
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

and on starting any service the server shows me this

```
sh-4.2$ systemctl start sshd
Failed to start sshd.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status sshd.service' for details
```

What is the issue? I have been trying hard to get the server working. but I am not being able to start the server. Can anyone help me with the issue?

thanks

Comment: You have issues with wrong permissions. Probably you issued some `chown` or `chmod` operation on the wrong path. Do you remember? It would be best to reinitialize the server. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48845/how-to-revert-chown-command or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587373/cant-login-after-chown-command?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you for the comment, as far as i remember i didnt do any chmod commands. The issue mainly arises when i tried to access the server through solar putty with my windows pc. But unfortunately i just got messed up with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately to say that the whole instance was corrupted. I had to remove the instance I had no other way. Well, I did try to mount the corrupted partition to somewhere else and tried to set up the firewall but it also didn't help.